# Python convert list of nested dict to dataframe with keys as column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert list of nested dict to dataframe with keys as column names and value as rows.

```
l = [
  {
   "Items": {
      "a": {
       "Value": 10          
      },
      "b": {
       "Value": 20          
      },
      "c": {
       "Value": 30          
      }
   }
 },
 {
   "Items": {
      "a": {
       "Value": 100          
      },
      "b": {
       "Value": 200          
      },
      "c": {
       "Value": 300          
      }
   }
 },
 {
   "Items": {
      "a": {
       "Value": 1000          
      },
      "b": {
       "Value": 2000          
      },
      "c": {
       "Value": 3000          
      }
   }
 }
]
```

Convert above data to dataframe like this -

```
| a    | b    | c    |
 --------------------
| 10   | 20   | 30   |
| 100  | 200  | 300  |
| 1000 | 2000 | 3000 |
```

I wrote below script to convert the data in desired format but I want to know if there is an optimal way to do the same.

```
results = {}
l_of_d = [d["Items"] for d in l]

for d in l_of_d:
  if k in results:
     results[k].append(d[k]['Value'])
  else:
     values = []
     values.append(d[k]['Value'])
     results[k] = values

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an optimal way to get your desired output

```
def convert_dict_df(data):

  df = pd.DataFrame()
  for item in data:
     parsed_dict = {key:value["Value"] for key, value in item['Items'].items()}
 
    df = df.append(parsed_dict, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
      a     b     c
0    10    20    30
1   100   200   300
2  1000  2000  3000
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it is better way to do it:

```py
results = {k: [d["Items"][k]["Value"] for d in l] for k in l[0]["Items"].keys()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
```

Comment: using multiple loops would also increase the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

***Optimal is :***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([x['Items'] for x in l])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x['Value'])
print(df)
```

***See Below Image for Results:***

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `DataFrame` can actually handle a list of dicts, just need to extract the "Value":

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: d[k]['Value'] for k in d} for d in [x["Items"] for x in l]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey added mine to the mix below also, I think that is the optimal

```
start = time()
df = pd.DataFrame([x['Items'] for x in l])
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x['Value'])
print(time() -start)
print(df)

start = time()
df = pd.DataFrame([{k: d[k]['Value'] for k in d} for d in [x["Items"] for x in l]])
print(time() -start)
print(df)    

start = time()
results = {k: [d["Items"][k]["Value"] for d in l] for k in l[0]["Items"].keys()}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(results)
print(time() -start)
print(df)
```

mine:

```
start = time()
pd_dict = {}
for item in l:
    for k, val in item['Items'].items():
        ll = pd_dict.setdefault(k, []) 
        ll.append(val['Value'])
df =pd.DataFrame(pd_dict)
print(time() -start)
print(df)
```

Results

```
0.0009181499481201172
      a     b     c
0    10    20    30
1   100   200   300
2  1000  2000  3000
0.00016617774963378906
      a     b     c
0    10    20    30
1   100   200   300
2  1000  2000  3000
0.00013256072998046875
      a     b     c
0    10    20    30
1   100   200   300
2  1000  2000  3000
0.00012636184692382812
      a     b     c
0    10    20    30
1   100   200   300
2  1000  2000  3000
```